# Many to many MVC 5 Model Code first join table

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, many-to-many, entity-framework-5, join

I have a perfect working code with One to many relationship between Team and Player. The drop down menu on Team side works and evertything is stored in db.

Now i want to introduce a join table so that one Team can have many players, and one player can join many team. I´m stumbling in the dark and need help forward. See my code below. Thanks in advance!
/Tha Pig

**Controllers**

PlayerController.cs

> namespace _1_to_N.Controllers {
>
> ```
> public class PlayerController : Controller
> {
>     private _1_to_NContext db = new _1_to_NContext();
>
>     // GET: Player
>     public ActionResult Index()
>     {
>         var players = db.Players.Include(p => p.Team);
>         return View(players.ToList());
>     }
> ```

TeamController.cs

> namespace _1_to_N.Controllers {
>
> ```
> public class TeamController : Controller
> {
>     private _1_to_NContext db = new _1_to_NContext();
>
>     // GET: Team
>     public ActionResult Index()
>     {
>         return View(db.Teams.ToList());
>     }
> ```

**MODELS:**

namespace _1_to_N.Models.cs

> > {
> >         public class _1_to_NContext : DbContext
> >         {
>
> ```
>     public _1_to_NContext() : base("name=_1_to_NContext")
>     {
>     }
>
>     public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<_1_to_N.Models.Team> Teams { get; set; }
>
>     public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<_1_to_N.Models.Player> Players { get; set; }
>
> } }
> ```

Player.cs

> namespace _1_to_N.Models
>   {
>
> ```
> public class Player
> {
>     public int PlayerId { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public int TeamId { get; set; }
>
>     public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
> } }
> ```

Team.cs

> namespace _1_to_N.Models{
>
> ```
> public class Team
> {
>     public int TeamId { get; set; }
>     [Required]
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public string City { get; set; }
>     public DateTime Founded { get; set; }
>
>     public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; } 
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to alter the `Team` property on `Player` to:

```
public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
```

Entity Framework will automatically discern an M2M exists and create a join table.

Comment: Thank you very much! Ok, i can now see the join table with correct id:s, and now i want to store values into TeamId and PlayerId in joint table...further the drop down menu disapeared from the team view when writing the code above...

Comment: The methodology for editing a M2M relationship is a little different and a little more complex. I have a post covering how to do that in detail that will likely help you: http://cpratt.co/associating-related-items-in-a-collection-via-a-listbox/

Comment: I´m sorry to bother you again..I´ve been trying for days now and i don´t get it, from my simple example, how to code so that my primary id`s, TeamId and PlayerId getting saved into the Joint Table, it can´t be that hard, but myaybe my brain is to slow..Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: It would be best to open a new question with your current problem. Send me a link and I'll check it out.

Comment: Indeed thank you, Chris! [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943512/many-to-many-mvc-5-model-first-write-to-join-table